# Wrong conditional blocks grayed out by Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Fairly typical setup:

```
#ifdef MSVC
 ...
#else
 ...
#endif
```

I know `MSVC` is set since the code runs but the IDE is graying out the wrong part, so Intellisense is also messed up on vars/methods called in the block.

Is this just another "delete the NCB" issue with pre-2010 VC++ or is there another fix?

Comment: It's more complicated than "delete the NCB". See my answer to [the same question about VS 2005][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586672/disable-or-fix-ifdef-sensitive-colouring-and-intellisense-in-visual-studio

Comment: Hmm, I was more interested in "There are some things you could try" but you didn't list any of them. I don't want to force VS2010 as many developers I work with are still on 2008. Unless I can get away with the Express edition perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a ready-made list of things to try, but basically anything that changes the solution landscape (things like reordering projects, sharing/unsharing source files between projects) has a chance of fixing the problem. But no matter what you do, even if it works for a long time, VS will eventually go wonky again. There really is only one practical solution: upgrade to VS 2010 or VS 2012.