# Greyed out C# preprocessor directives in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

In Visual Studio 2017, how do you stop C# preprocessor directives (#if etc.. ) from greying out the code, and ideally also allow all blocks to be Code-Completed, refactored, etc.

[An answer for VS 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586672/disable-or-fix-ifdef-sensitive-colouring-and-intellisense-in-visual-studio/20651843#20651843) does not work with 2017..

Comment: Why would you want that? It's showing you what code will be dropped if compiled under the current settings - very useful IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, normally very useful.  However, not in the scenario where you are developing code for multiple platforms simultaneously.  My app will run on 3 different hardware platforms, and when I work on a feature it often needs platform specific changes for each platform.
If a better approach to developing code destined for multiple different places exists, that might be a different but useful question..

Comment: If there was a very fast way to change the target compilation (One click, not waiting more than a few seconds) then that would also solve the issue as I could do that whenever i move to a new block of code.  But I am currently jumping between the platform specific codes multiple times a minute, and making do without it all being syntax highlighted.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's not only about graying, that code is excluded from being compiled, intelli-sensed, refactored, etc. It become a comment. Though I hate people who use `#if TEST`to quickly comment some parts of code and if I see it then I'll change member names, so they suffer when uncomment `#define TEST`.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach altogether - create a different project (dll) for each target platform, have all the classes in these projects implement the same interfaces, and have the target platform specific code there. Then you can work on the main code of the application (I'm guessing most of the code is not target specific) in one project, and complete the implementation for each target specific dll at once, without having to gray out parts of your code or jump between compilation settings.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, I also mean that I want all compilation, refactoring etc.. to work.  I just didn't know which terminology would be best.  thanks

Comment: The `#if` and `#else` part may add something what collide (e.g. define method with same name, but different number of parameters). You are very likely to face uncompile-able code if you make pre-compiler to simply ignore `#if`s. I didn't develop anything for multi-platform yet, but there should be other possibilities to organize platform specific code, right?

Comment: hmm, so in that case it sounds like just having Syntax Highlighting would be all I can hope for in an answer?  Even if it's like vim does it, not knowing the whole project.   Code-Completion local to the #if block it's in should be theoretically possible too right?  I think they did it in VS 2005 but it's looking like the option doesn't exist in 2017... ): Thanks for the input all

Comment: Note they re-enabled this option in VS 2019 under: `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > View > Inactive Code > Show Inactive Blocks`

Comment: "If there was a very fast way to change the target compilation"  There is with 2 clicks, the **Solution Configuration** is a dropdown list in the Standard toolbar.  One click expands the list, the next selects the new active configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality was removed from Visual Studio 2017, but was restored since Visual Studio 2019

It can be enabled at:
`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > View > Inactive Code > Show Inactive Blocks`